# Roslyn diagnostics reported through CompilationAnalysisContext.ReportDiagnostic do not show up in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have created a Roslyn analyzer using the *Analyzer with Code Fix* template in Visual Studio 2022. Everything works in unit tests, but no diagnostics are shown up in Visual Studio.

A minimal example showing the problem:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class DummyAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule1 = new ("D001", "SymbolAction", "SymbolAction", "Test", DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, true);
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule2 = new ("D002", "CompilationAction", "CompilationAction", "Test", DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, true);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => [Rule1, Rule2];

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.EnableConcurrentExecution();

        context.RegisterSymbolAction(c => c.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule1, c.Symbol.Locations.FirstOrDefault())), SymbolKind.Method);

        context.RegisterCompilationAction(CompilationAction);
    }

    private void CompilationAction(CompilationAnalysisContext context)
    {
        foreach (var syntaxTree in context.Compilation.SyntaxTrees)
        {
            var compilationUnitSyntax = syntaxTree.GetRoot(context.CancellationToken) as CompilationUnitSyntax;
            var typeDeclarationSyntax = compilationUnitSyntax?.Members.OfType<BaseNamespaceDeclarationSyntax>().SelectMany(syntax => syntax.Members).OfType<TypeDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (typeDeclarationSyntax != null)
                context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule2, typeDeclarationSyntax.GetLocation()));
        }
    }
}
```

In unit tests, both `Rule1` and `Rule2` produce diagnostics as expected. However, in Visual Studio only diagnostics from `Rule1` are shown, despite debugger confirming that both `context.ReportDiagnostic` calls are being hit. It seems that no diagnostics reported through `CompilationAnalysisContext.ReportDiagnostic` are shown at all regardless to what I put there.

How can I solve the issue? Rewriting everything to use `SymbolAnalysisContext.ReportDiagnostic` would be too complex task as my analyzer needs to check relationships between several symbols.

I already made sure that no diagnostics are being suppressed through Visual Studio settings.

Comment: What is the .NET version? The sample requires C# 9.0 or greater.

Comment: It's .NET Standard 2.0 with LangVersion = latest specified in project file.

Comment: I tested the sample. It is able to hit the break point and generate Diagnostics. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjraB.png)